# Set project version in Jenkins Pipeline with the Artifactory Gradle plugin

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

We want to define the project version for our Gradle project during the build of our project in the Jenkins pipeline, which will include a timestamp and a git-commit-id.  (**20180625180158-b8ad8df0dc0356a91707eaa241de7d62df6a29f2**)

```
void defineVersion() {
sh "git rev-parse HEAD > .git/commit-id"
commitId = readFile('.git/commit-id')
timestamp =  getCurrentTimestamp()
version = timestamp+'-'+commitId
}
```

This function will determine the version I want to publish our artifact with.
Next I use the Artifactory Gradle plugin to publish, but I can't find a way to set/override the project version. I want the jar to be published with version **20180625180158-b8ad8df0dc0356a91707eaa241de7d62df6a29f2**

```
version = defineVersion() // how can we incorperate this version in our gradle build/publish?

gradleBuild = Artifactory.newGradleBuild()
gradleBuild.useWrapper = true
gradleBuild.deployer(
        repo: env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ? 'libs-releases-local' : 'libs-snapshots-local',
        server: Artifactory.server('artifactory-global'))

gradleBuild.run tasks: 'clean build artifactoryPublish'
```

How can we achieve this? Also I would like to pass other parameters like **-x test** to the run command to skip tests in this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can add parameters throug the `switches` parameter: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/artifactory/

With this you add the necessary parameters like `'-x test -Pversion=' + version`

For my use case I added a version property to my **build.gradle**: `version = "${version}"` so it can be overridden with the command above.

Comment: need to do something similar. So after you added version = "${version}" in the build.gradle how did the line ended to be in jenkinsfile?
I tried this but it doesn´t work (for example version 5): 
buildInfo = rtGradle.run rootDir: "/path/test", buildFile: 'build.gradle', tasks: 'clean build -Pversion = + 5'